# Why does my .off() event handler not turn off the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my `resetTable` function, after it creates a new table, at the very bottom I call my `hover()` function, so the sketch-pad will work. However, because the `hover()` function includes changing the background color of my table cells, I need to turn it off so that my `trail()` function can just changed the opacity of the table cells.

I made a `resetTableTrail` function to where it calls the original `resetTable()` function, then is supposed to turn off the `hover()` function, and allow for the `trail()` function to take over, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is a live demo: http://codepen.io/hgducharme/pen/bmyGc?editors=001

Here is the relevant parts of my code:

```
$(function() {
  buildTable(16);
  hover();
  resetTable();
  trail();
  randomColorHover();
  resetTableTrail();
});



// Hover Function To Add Colors
function hover() {
  $('td').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(90,188,215)');
  },

  function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(90,188,215)');
  });
};


// Rebuilds Table When Button Is Clicked
function resetTable() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {

    var choice = prompt("How many columns and rows would you like? Please pick a number between (1 & 64).", "16");

    if (choice < 1 || choice > 64) {
      alert("That was not a valid entry, please specify a number between (1 & 64)");
      return null;
    }

    else {
      var resetColor = $('td').css('background-color', 'rgb(215,215,215)');
      var removeTable = $('table').remove();
      buildTable(choice);
      $('td').on("click", hover() );
    }
  });
}

// If the hover call is in the original resetTable function
// Then it doesn't allow for the trail mode to properly run
// So I created a new function that allows for the trail mode
// To run properly, and also allows for the normal button
// To reset the grid and then call the hover function 
// When the grid resets
function resetTableTrail() {
  $('#trail').click(function() {

    resetTable();

    $('td').off("click", hover() );

    trail();

  });
}


// Creates Trail
function trail() {
  $("#trail").click(function() {
    $('td').hover(function() {
      $(this).css('opacity', '0');
    },

    function() {
      $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really scale your demo's down to the minimal needed to represent your issue.

With that said, I'm not sure what behavior to expect from demo but you are using incorrect syntax to pass event handler to `on()`

You want to pass the function as a reference not call it.

Change:

```
$('td').on("click", hover() );
```

To

```
$('td').on("click", hover );
```

Do same for `off()`

I'm guessing in your `hover()` that you want to affect only the element clciked. Since you are passing the handler as a reference, you can access the current instance of `td` clicked within your hover function using `this`.

```
function hover() {
    var $el = $(this).hover(function () {
        $el.css('background-color', 'rgb(90,188,215)');
    },

    function () {
        $el.css('background-color', 'rgb(90,188,215)');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`off()` shall take reference of the function that was attached by `on()`.

So this

```
$('td').off("click", hover() );
```

is wrong as your hover does not return any function.

You'd better use namespaced events here. To set:

```
.on('click.somename', function() {} )
```

and to remove:

```
.off('click.somename'); // note - does not need function reference here.
```

But I personally would use here just one handler attached to the table itself:

```
$('table').on('click','td', function() { ... })
```

In this case you don't need to add/remove handlers on table manipulations.